# calculating with two double variables

Tags: c#, math, double, calculation

This is the simplest form of my problem and I wonder how this happen?

```
Console.WriteLine(3.12 * 3.14);
```

What it do to give this result?

```
9.796800000000001
```

It makes me problem for my general code and program. How to avoid this and give me the exact desired output?

Comment: Thanks, I wonder why I didn't know about this :( sorry if my question is so amateurish. but I can't find the answer how to avoid this problem in the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `float`

```
        var x = (float)3.12;
        // or var x = 3.12f
        var y = (float)3.14;
        var result = x * y;
        Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. why (double) doesn't work. and another amateurish question, why `float pi = 3.14;` gets an error and it needs `(float)3.14`?

Comment: Its about hardware(CPU) calculations for 64bit floating-points. Compiler allocates 64bit memory for `3.14` and `float` is 32bit. `(float)` casting a 64bit variable(`double`) to 32bit variable(`float`). `3.14f` creates directly 32bit.

Comment: Of course you can use `decimal` too. Rounding errors occur on 64bit. Not on 32bit and 128bit. `decimal` provides more sensitivity but need more CPU cycles.

Comment: Yes, I found this useful for anyone who have the same problem as me too :
http://www.net-informations.com/q/faq/float.html
I see `float` could make problem in rounding somewhere too. Thanks for all the answers.